# Infinite square well: what's the intuition behind there being no chance to measure energy in states where n is even?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry

In an infinite square well of width $a$ (running from 0 to $a$), the wavefunction is,
$$|\psi_n\rangle=\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)$$

What's the intuition behind there being no chance to measure energy in states where $n$ is even? I've searched for this answer and, mathematically, I can see that for even $n$ $|\psi_n\rangle$ is uneven and so the Fourier transform will give me these coefficients. But what is the intuition (or physical interpretation) behind $c_n = 0$ for even $n$ (and thus the chance for energy $E_n$ being $P_n=|c_n|^2$ being zero for even $n$)?

Comment: We will need more information about how $|\psi_n\rangle$ is defined here. A priori, there is no reason why the system would be unable to be in some of the energy eigenstates.

Comment: @Noiralef $|\psi_n>=\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin{(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)}$. Here $a$ is the width of the well which runs from $0$ to $a$.

Comment: Why do you think that $c_n$ should be zero for even $n$?

Comment: @Noiralef Given $$|\psi\rangle=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} & 0\leq x \leq a \\ 0 & x<0, x>a \end{cases}$$ I used $$ c_n = \int \psi_n^*(x) \psi(x) dx $$ and found the expansion coefficients as $$ c_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when n is even} \\ \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{n \pi} & \text{when n is odd} \end{cases}.$$

Then, $P_n=|c_n|^2=\frac{8}{n\pi}$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Why do you think  you have to project that $\left| \left. \psi \right. \right>$ on the $\psi_n(x)$? The  $\psi_n(x)$ (for all $n\gt0$ )are the eigenstates and the corresponding eigenvalues are allowed for all positive values of $n$.

Comment: @GiorgioP because I am looking for the $c_n$ as they will give me the probability of measuring energy $E_n$.

Comment: If you have a specific wave function that you are trying to decompose, then you should put that in the text of the question. As the question reads at this moment, it doesn't make sense. There are eigenfunctions and eigenvalues for all integer $n$ values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What energies you can measure, and what the corresponding probabilities are, depends on the state that the system is in.
In general, the system can be in any state $|\psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n |\psi_n\rangle$, where $c_n$ can be *anything* (as long as $\sum_n |c_n|^2 = 1$).

If you know that your system is in a certain state $|\psi\rangle$, you can calculate the set of coefficients $c_n$ that belong to that specific state.
In the comments you write that your state is $\langle x | \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt a}$.
In that case, yes, all $c_n$ with even $n$ are zero.
But please keep in mind that this is not the case at all, generally.

You were asking *why* those coefficients are zero.
Maybe the following helps.
As you noted yourself, the $\psi_n(x)$ are odd functions (when reflected at the center of the well, $x=a/2$) and $\psi(x)$ is an even function, the integral of an odd times as even function is zero.
This concept is formalized in QM by introducing the parity operator $\hat P$, defined as $\hat P |x\rangle = |a/2 - x\rangle$.
($\hat P$ reflects the wave function at the center of the well, it is hermitian and $\hat P^2 = 1$.)
Eigenstates of $\hat P$ with eigenvalue $+1$ have "even parity", eigenstates with eigenvalue $-1$ have "odd parity".

- Since $\hat P$ is hermitian, eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are orthogonal.
  That means that even parity states always have zero overlap with odd parity states.
- Since $[\hat H, \hat P] = 0$, all eigenstates of $\hat H$ have a well-defined parity (i.e. they are eigenstates of $\hat P$).
  In fact, $|\psi_n\rangle$ has odd parity if $n$ is even and vice versa.
- Your state $|\psi\rangle$ has even parity and therefore no overlap with odd parity eigenstates of $\hat H$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I never realized that $|\psi\rangle$ does not _have_ to be the state I assumed. This really made things click for me, I'm sorry for any frustration I might have caused you.